# Passing 2D-array to VBA/UDF function from sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am on Excel 2010.

When a VBA user-defined function, say make2DArray, outputs a variant representing a 2D-array, this 2D-array can be then used as an input to another VBA function, say someFunction. While calling the functions from within VBA code. It works fine.

However when doing the same, passing make2DArray output as argument to someFunction, from within the sheet (via a formula in a cell), then it seems to work only for 2D-array with **2 or more rows**. Generating 2D-array with 1 row would fail. It seems that the 1-row 2D-array is then transformed automatically into an equivalent 1D-array.

A small example :

```
Option Explicit

'returns last (top-most, right-most) element
Function someFunction(v As Variant) As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
        Debug.Print "Dim-1 size", UBound(v, 1) - LBound(v, 1) + 1
        Debug.Print "Dim-2 size", UBound(v, 2) - LBound(v, 2) + 1
    On Error GoTo 0

    someFunction = v(UBound(v, 1), UBound(v, 2))
End Function

Function make2DArray(h As Integer, w As Integer) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j  As Integer
    Dim v2d As Variant

    ReDim v2d(1 To h, 1 To w)
    For i = 1 To h
        For j = 1 To w
            v2d(i, j) = i * j
        Next j
    Next i

    make2DArray = v2d
End Function

Sub test()
    'also works when called from sheet
    Debug.Print someFunction(make2DArray(2, 3)) 'returns 6
    'doesn't work when called from sheet
    Debug.Print someFunction(make2DArray(1, 3)) 'returns 3
End Sub
```

The test function will work fine from within VBA. Similarly =someFunction(make2DArray(2, 3)) or any =someFunction(make2DArray(i, j)) cell formula would work well for i>1, however =someFunction(make2DArray(1, 3)) or any =someFunction(make2DArray(1, j)) will only produce a #VALUE! result in the sheet.

My question : Is this behavior documented somewhere? Is there a way to avoid the "casting" from 2D-array to 1D-array for 1-row 2D-arrays?

Comment: To avoid confusion you may want to swap your *w* and *h*. A 2-D array passed back to the worksheet regards the first rank as the number of *rows* and the second rank as the number of *columns*.

Comment: Just tested your `=someFunction(make2DArray(2, 4))` and it returns *8* which is the value at the ubound of both ranks.

Comment: @Jeeped. Thanks. I did swap w and h as suggested. =someFunction(make2DArray(2, 4)) produces 8, as expected, while =someFunction(make2DArray(1, 4)) outputs #VALUE!, which is what my question is about.

Comment: Don't really know what to say; I'm certainly not making things up. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1bJA.png).

Comment: Can you please try =someFunction(make2DArray(1,4)) instead? This one should error out as the first argumemt is 1.

Comment: Yes, as the output of the `make2DArray(1,4)` is passed back to Excel, Excel converts it to a 1D array, and then passes that 1D array to the `someFunction` function.  It is always a bad idea to use the Excel-modified result of a UDF as a parameter to a UDF.  Instead pass `h` and `w` to `someFunction` itself, and have `someFunction` invoke `make2DArray`.  (I.e. call it as `=someFunction(1, 4)`.)

Comment: tbh, I've never seen that before. It is like it is using transpose to convert a 2-D (one row) array into a 1-D array. I consider this a bug in that the VBA overhead is looking at a 2-D variant array with one 'row' (e.g. 1 as ubound first rank) and converting it to a 1-D array with the original ubound second rank as the ubound of the sole 1-D rank. For universality, the only suggestion I can come up with would be error control; I'll post a suggestion below.

Comment: fwiw **THANK YOU!** for asking an intelligent and well documented question about programming. It seems that nine out of ten inquiries made to the [tag:excel] tag lately have been nothing more than software specifications with a lame *'I'm a noob and don't know how to do this'* narrative.

Answer (score 1):

From my comments:

> <sub>I've never seen that before. It is like it is using transpose to convert a 2-D (one row) array into a 1-D array. I consider this a bug in that the VBA overhead is looking at a 2-D variant array with one 'row' (e.g. 1 as ubound first rank) and converting it to a 1-D array with the original ubound second rank as the ubound of the sole 1-D rank. For universality, the only suggestion I can come up with would be error control; I'll post a suggestion below.</sub>

Here is some error control to overcome the rogue 2-D to 1-D array conversion.

```
'returns bottom-right element of 2D-array
Function someFunction(v As Variant) 'As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
        Debug.Print "Dim-1 size", UBound(v, 1) - LBound(v, 1) + 1
        Debug.Print "Dim-2 size", UBound(v, 2) - LBound(v, 2) + 1
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Debug.Print IsArray(v)
    'Debug.Print UBound(v, 1) & ":" & UBound(v, 2)

    On Error GoTo err_1D_array
    someFunction = v(UBound(v, 1), UBound(v, 2))
    Exit Function

err_1D_array:
    someFunction = v(UBound(v))

End Function
```

Comment: I'm actually curious as to whether this bug may be more CPU efficient than a typical application.transpose function that reduces a 2-D array to a 1-D array when the first rank's ubound is 1. For that matter, it may also be more efficient when the second rank's ubound is one versus the standard application.transpose(application.transpose(v)).

Comment: Transpose is quite an efficient function but at best it does involve creating a copy of the array and therefore this costs. At worst it involves slow round-trips between Excel and VBA - I have never found a case where transpose is faster than accessing the arrays directly (but such a case probably exists!)

Comment: I agree that the error control does work and help circumventing the array size issue. Before accepting this answer, I'll wait a bit longer in case someone knows if this behavior is documented somewhere (I'd like to understand if there is a reason for it, or if it is just a "bug")

Answer (score 1):

UDFs should really copy with parameters being either a range, or a vector, or an array, or a scalar constant, or an array/vector output from some other function. 
SomeFunction({1,2,3}) gets a 1D vector array
 SomeFunction({1;2;3}) gets a 2D array
 SomeFunction(Range as variant) gets a variant containing a range object whose Value2 property always returns either a scalar or a 2D array.